# How to paginate both parent and child objects at a time in Spring Data Jpa

Tags: hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have 100 parent records in data base and each parent recored in having 1000 child records. I want to limit 10 parent records per page and 10 child's for each parent. How can we achieve it in Spring Data JPA

Comment: You cannot page the children. You should rethink what you want to do with the data

Comment: As @SimonMartinelli said, you cannot do that. However, call one more SQL command for each parent record is possible, in total you only call 11 SQL commands. It's not a big deal.

Comment: @luanvu 2 queries are enough

Comment: @Simon Martinelli I would like to know those 2 queries. I used to face this problem before, but I forgot how I resolved it.

Comment: With the first query you get the 10 parents and with the second all the childeren of these 10 parents

Answer (score 0):

At least with the entity model this is not possible as you can't have a partially initialized collection, but I think this is a perfect use case for [Blaze-Persistence Entity Views](https://github.com/Blazebit/blaze-persistence#entity-view-usage) which has built-in support for this through lateral joins.

I created the library to allow easy mapping between JPA models and custom interface or abstract class defined models, something like Spring Data Projections on steroids. The idea is that you define your target structure(domain model) the way you like and map attributes(getters) via JPQL expressions to the entity model.

A DTO model for your use case could look like the following with Blaze-Persistence Entity-Views:

```
@EntityView(Parent.class)
public interface ParentDto {
    @IdMapping
    Long getId();
    String getName();
    @Limit(limit = "10", order = "id asc")
    Set<ChlidDto> getChildren();

    @EntityView(Child.class)
    interface ChlidDto {
        @IdMapping
        Long getId();
        String getName();
    }
}
```

Querying is a matter of applying the entity view to a query, the simplest being just a query by id.

`ParentDto a = entityViewManager.find(entityManager, ParentDto.class, id);`

The Spring Data integration allows you to use it almost like Spring Data Projections: https://persistence.blazebit.com/documentation/entity-view/manual/en_US/index.html#spring-data-features

```
Page<ParentDto> findAll(Pageable pageable);
```

The best part is, it will only fetch the state that is actually necessary!